# Hover state on circles

Tags: html, css, hover, geometry, transition

I'm designing this [page](http://creativusmouse.com/Proteus/html_preview/index.html) that contains four big circles with CSS3 transitions and I'm trying to make it work on IE8. I know CSS3 transitions don't work on old versions of IE therefore I just wanted to have these circles work on normal hover without the transitions.
I really can't figure out how to achieve this. Hope someone could help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using Jquery for the same. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:hover` on your elements, like this `#id_of_circe:hover {...}`

Comment: I've achieved what I wanted using opacity as well as :hover but the result got inverted lol